# Bootstrap hiding contents on small screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, hide

I am having problems with bootstrap's responsive design. It is hiding some photos and iframes, which I am not willing to hide. I tried setting `.col-xs` `col-sm` and everything, also tried `.visible.sm` , but it still does not show anything. Any idea if I can override this hide style and tell bootstrap that it is important for me to visualize those contents?

EDIT: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/N5n7f/) is the code snippet I am talking about. Of course, I am using bootsrap. I am asking for a general solution, if there is a class that overrides bootstrap's hiding. Sorry if the code is not too tidied, but I am using the MEAN stack with jade as view engine, so I just copied this out of the browser and tidied it up.

```
.container
            .row
                .well(ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-if="page!=undefined")
                    .row
                        .col-md-1
                            img(ng-src="{{page.profileImage}}" src="")
                        .col-md-9.pull-left
                            h5{{page.from.name}} - 
                                span(ng-show="page.type=='link'") shared link
                                span(ng-show="page.embedLink || page.type=='video'") added video
                                span(ng-show="page.type=='photo'") added picture
                            .row.content(ng-show="page.type=='link'", style="margin-top:20px;")
                                .col-md-6
                                    div.image-link-container
                                        a(href="{{page.link}}" target="_blank")
                                            img(ng-src="{{page.picture}}" src="")
                                .col-md-6
                                    p.description
                                        | {{page.name}}
                                    p 
                                        a(href="{{page.caption}}" target="_blank") {{page.caption}}
                                    p.message {{page.message}}
                            .row.content(ng-show="page.type=='photo'" style="margin-top:20px;")
                                .col-md-6
                                    div.image-link-container(ng-hide="page.embedLink")
                                        img(ng-src="{{page.postPhoto}}" src="")
                                .col-md-6
                                    p.message.description
                                        |{{page.message}}
                                        br
                                        | {{page.caption}}
                            .row.content(ng-show="page.embedLink || page.type=='video'", style="margin-top:20px;")
                                iframe(ng-src="{{trustSrc(page.embedLink)}}", src="", style="widht:560px;height:315px", frameborder="0", allowfullscreen, target="_top", type="application/x-shockwave-flash")

                        .col-md-2
                            .well
                                .row.fb-action-row.text-center(ng-click="like(page)")
                                    img(ng-src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B_EenlQcPPQvd0ZhX053UTFpX00/Add-Facebook-Like-Button-in-Magento.jpg" width="30" height="30")
                                    span.fb-action Likes 
                                        span {{page.likes.data.length || 0}}
                                .row.fb-action-row.text-center(ng-click="commentWindow(page)")
                                    img(ng-src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B_EenlQcPPQvd0ZhX053UTFpX00/comment.png" width="30" height="30")
                                    span.fb-action Comment 
                                        span {{page.comments.data.length || 0}}
                                .row.fb-action-row.text-center(ng-click="share(page)")
                                    img(ng-src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B_EenlQcPPQvd0ZhX053UTFpX00/share.jpg" width="30" height="30")
                                    span.fb-action Shares 
                                        span {{page.shares.count || 0}}
```

Comment: html, css would be helpful ...along with question. I doubt anybody can suggest you anything without it

Comment: It would be better of you would paste the computed html code

Comment: Oh, and whats exactly missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How i see it, after adding bootstrap to your code on fiddle: it's not your content div (div.col-md-9.pull-left) hiding, but it's the one with social media (div.col-md-2) taking all the space on top of the content.

What work for me: try defining its (div.col-md-2) behavior on smaller screens (col-xs-2) or pull it as well (add pull-fight or pull-left).

Hope it helps ;)

EDIT:
For the future use - Jsfiddle for easy bootstrap code sharing: http://www.bootply.com/qZvpz3Jkha